# How do you select*from with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the records of a table where three columns match up, but i'm getting no results in return. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT *
FROM Flights
WHERE Departure_IATA_Code = 'STN'
  AND Arrival_IATA_Code = 'DBN'
  AND Departure_Date = 2018-04-16
```

Create table statements

```
CREATE TABLE `Flights` (
 `Flight_Number` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Aircraft_ID` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Departure_IATA_Code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Departure_Date` date NOT NULL,
 `Arrival_IATA_Code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Cost` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `Departure_Time` time NOT NULL,
 `Flight_Duration` time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Flight_Number`,`Aircraft_ID`,`Departure_IATA_Code`,`Departure_Date`,`Arrival_IATA_Code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Yes, check your query without the filters, one by one. What makes you think this is wrong? Maybe there is no data with these conditions.

Comment: date='2018-4-16' missing single quotes :/

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486)

Comment: It was the missing quote marks for the date. I was trying to do it as a prepared statement in php.

Comment: @dominthomas retract the question if you have the answer and it was a typo that serves no other purpose.

Comment: Double quotes would also do.  But `2018-04-16`, which equals `1998` is _not_ what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Flights
WHERE Departure_IATA_Code = 'STN'
AND Arrival_IATA_Code = 'DBN'
AND Departure_Date = '2018-04-16';
```

Comment: `Departure_Date` is already a `date`. No need for the conversion.